# Unable to push Grails 2.1.0 application to Predix platform

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry, predix

I am not able to push my grails application into Predix platform. I am very new to predix and here is what I am using to push the war application into predix `cf push appstore --no-start -p target\oas-0.2.war --no-manifest` and as per the project requirement we are supposed to use jre version 1.7 and hence `cf set-env appstore JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE "[jre: { version: 1.7.0_+ }]"` is being used.

We are able to run the Grails application by itself and was even able to successfully deploy and run on tomcat but the same .war file is not being able to push into Predix.

**LOGS**

```
2016-11-22T16:02:54.54+0530 [STG/0]      ERR
2016-11-22T16:03:04.79+0530 [STG/38]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (111M)
2016-11-22T16:03:15.35+0530 [DEA/38]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 0fd0a5ed-e88c-464b-8eb7-59998d99c789
2016-11-22T16:03:19.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT     [CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-63703"] 2016-11-22T16:03:19.78+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Initialization processed in 559 ms
2016-11-22T16:03:19.79+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService           INFO    Starting service Catalina
2016-11-22T16:03:19.79+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine            INFO    Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
2016-11-22T16:03:19.81+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT                                                                                                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.76+0530 [App/0]      ERR     Nov 22, 2016 10:33:23 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars                                                 2016-11-22T16:03:23.76+0530 [App/0]      ERR INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.                2016-11-22T16:03:23.76+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase             SEVERE  ContainerBase.addChild: start:
2016-11-22T16:03:23.76+0530 [App/0]      OUT org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]                                                                                                                                          2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)                                              2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)                                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)                                         2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)                                     2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)                                              2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)                                                             2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                                                                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of type [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]                                                                                                                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1324)                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:647)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:108)                                    2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)                                                 2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    ... 10 more                                                                                                             2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener                                        2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)                          2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)                          2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)            2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1295)                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    ... 14 more
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             SEVERE  Error deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]                                                                                          2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)                                              2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)                                                2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)                                         2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)                                     2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)                                              2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                                      2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 3,959 ms                                                                                             2016-11-22T16:03:23.77+0530 [App/0]      OUT [CONTAINER] pplicationStartupFailureDetectingLifecycleListener SEVERE  Error: Application '/oas-production-0.2' failed (state = FAILED): see Tomcat's logs for details. Halting Tomcat.                                                                                                        2016-11-22T16:03:23.81+0530 [DEA/38]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections                                                                   2016-11-22T16:03:23.82+0530 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 0fd0a5ed-e88c-464b-8eb7-59998d99c789 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"0fd0a5ed-e88c-464b-8eb7-59998d99c789", "version"=>"6e5da56c-8eb8-4a1d-973a-b5464d74479a", "instance"=>"f0a3076e34e644278859622475dc4c12", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>148, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1479810803}
2016-11-22T16:03:23.82+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 0fd0a5ed-e88c-464b-8eb7-59998d99c789 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"0fd0a5ed-e88c-464b-8eb7-59998d99c789", "version"=>"6e5da56c-8eb8-4a1d-973a-b5464d74479a", "instance"=>"f0a3076e34e644278859622475dc4c12", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>148, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1479810803}
```

Kindly help me out with this regard. Let me know if I am in right direction to push an application into Predix.

**Links for the screen shot**

[Logs_ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiWKU.png)

[Logs_ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mq3k.png)

Thanks and Regards,
Akash

Comment: Maybe try upgrading to a version of Grails released more recently than 4 years ago?

Comment: As per the project requirement we are not supposed to use any other version other than 2.1.0. Please suggest me any other way to push this application into predix..

Answer (score -1):

From the logs it looks like its using Tomcat version 8.0.38. Are you using 8.x version of Tomcat when you are running your application locally as well? If not, can you try deploying to that version of tomcat to see if you are able to deploy successfully?

Comment: I tried to deploy the grails application into Tomcat 8+ server but that wasn't sucessful. And so I tried to deploy the application into Predix using the manifest file and when I use the manifest file to push an application into Predix I could see in the log that Tomcat 7.0.67 was being used and thats the same which we are using in our application.